# Apollo refetch query with same previous variables used in another component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, gql

I have a `useQuery` in file `A.ts` like so

```
const { data } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {
  variables: myQueryVariables
})
```

Now, I need to trigger a refetch of `MY_QUERY` but in another component in another file, in `B.ts`, but I need to use the *same variables* as I used in the last execution of the same query but I don't have access to `myQueryVariables` in `B.ts`

```
const { refetch } = useQuery(MY_QUERY);

// this refetches the query but without variables
refetch()
```

How can I trigger that refetch with the same variables without passing them in order to update the cache thus updating the UI?

Comment: pass refetch and variables from original hook by context or app state (redux/apollo local)

Comment: @xadm Can you explain what you mean by passing refetch by context or app state?